# Detecting infinite recursion in v8

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I am using google's v8 javascript engine to have an embedded js interpreter in my project, which must be able to execute user-provided code, but I am wondering if it is possible to set something up in advance of calling any user code which ensures that if the code tries to recurse indefinitely (or even if it just executes for too long), that it can somehow be made to abort, throw an otherwise uncaught exception, and report the issue back to the caller.

Thank you all for responses so far... yes, I realized not long after I posted this that I was basically asking for some kind of solution to the halting problem, which I know is unsolvable, and is actually far more than what I really need.

What I'd need is either some mechanism for detecting when something running in the v8 environment is returning quickly enough, or else simply a mechanism to detect if recursion is happening at all... my use cases are such that the end user should not be utilizing any recursion anyways, and if I can possibly even detect that, then I could reject it at that point instead of blindly executing it.   It would be allowed, however, for different threads, with different isolates to invoke the same functions at the same time, so I can't just use a static local variable to lock out another call to the same function.

Comment: So you want to solve the halting problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A compiler [V8 is definitely a compiler in this context, even if it isn't "always" a compiler] can detect recursion, but if the code is clever enough (for example depending on variables that aren't known at compile time), it's not possible to detect whether it has infinite or finite recursion.

I would simply state that "execution over X seconds is disallowed", and if the execution takes more than that long, abort it. You can do this by having a "watchdog thread", that gets triggered when the code completes - and if the watchdog thread gets to run X seconds, kill the main thread and report back to user-code. No, I don't know EXACTLY how to write this code in conjunction with V8.